# link_to in Foundation vertical navbar in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, haml

How can I put link_to redirecting to root_path in this HAML code?

```
    .icon-bar.large.vertical.four-up
     %a.item
      %img{:src => "/svgs/fi-home.svg"}/
      %label Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search lead me to this, https://rivalfox.com/blog/haml-best-practices/

So I would give the following a try,

```
= link_to root_path, class: ['btn', 'btn-default'] do
  = image_tag 'fi-home.svg'
  Home
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .icon-bar.large.vertical.four-up
   = link_to root_path, class: ['item'] do
   = image_tag "/svgs/fi-home.svg"
   %label Home
```

This works, thanks for help.

Comment: awesome, glad I could help.